# Protecting glossaries key against \MakeTextLowercase

Tags: glossaries

I'm using glossaries together with titlesec, which adds \MakeTextLowercase to the \section command. This breaks glossaries, since the key is now lower case.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{API}{API}{Application Programming Interface}
\begin{document}
    \section{\MakeTextLowercase{\Acrlong*{API}}}
\end{document}
```

Fails with

```
Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `api' has not been defined. \section{\MakeTextLowercase{\Acrlong*{API}}}
```

Is there a way to protect the key against this, other than changing it to lower case?

Comment: see `\NoCaseChange{...}` in the textcase documentation

Comment: The `glossaries` package advises against using commands like `\gls`, `\acrlong` etc in section headings. ([Why shouldn't I use commands like \gls in \section, \chapter, \caption etc?](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#whynoglsinsection)).

Comment: David Carlisle: Thank you, section{\NoCaseChange{\MakeTextLowercase{\Acrlong*{API}}}} worked

Nicola Talbot: Thanks for the hint. I my case, fortunately none of this applies.